# Why was a weekend support email sent when a normal user appealed a suspension using the contact form on Sunday?

Tags: support, email, account-suspension

I appealed my suspension on 27 ‎February ‎2022, ‏‎02:20 PM (Indian Standard Time) using [the contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact). Immediately, I received two emails from Stack Exchange. One was an automatic email regarding a ticket being created. Another one was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAit0.png):

> Hello!
>
> Please be aware that the support team does not monitor support tickets during the weekend or holidays, but we do offer on-call support for our Stack Overflow for Teams Enterprise and Business plans. If this is an emergency, please open a Severity 1 or 2 ticket via our [support portal](https://s.tk/ooo). If you're issue falls within our on-call SLA, someone should contact you within 15 minutes.
>
> For all other products and plans, we'll reach out as soon as we can the next business day.
>
> Thanks

I am not sure if this email should be sent to normal users like me. Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

Normal users refers to users who have nothing to do with *Stack Overflow for Teams Enterprise and Business plans*.

Comment: That anonymous email is  simply called a **canned response**. It's given when no one is in the office to reply to requests personally and to save time if the answer is always the same. Why do you think this might have been sent by error?

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні I received this kinda mail for the first time. I might have contacted SE on a weekend in the past but I didn't receive any such kinda email back then. Also, the email talks about 'Stack Overflow for Teams Enterprise and Business plans' stuff which are irrelevant to me.

Comment: The email is covering all possible scenarios. Maybe there are situations that someone from an enterprise or team also has an SE user account and uses that to contact staff with.

Comment: Teams Enterprise and Business plans users pay, a lot, to use Stack Overflow product, hence they deserve special support. "Normal users" as you call them, fall under "other products and plans" which is clearly mentioned in the email as well.

Comment: Is that “you’re” typo really present in the original email? Wow!

Comment: @Tim maybe you are really an issue, for SE... ;)

Comment: @Tim It's really present in the email. I didn't notice it until you informed me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do need to send a notification that we don't check the queues on weekends. It is sent for *all* inquiries, including the contact form, because customers do sometimes find the less-preferred path of contacting us and they need to be notified that a response will not come until Monday. Besides, you'd be surprised how many people previously would submit the contact form and reply back to the confirmation multiple times that they haven't received a reply yet, because it's the weekend.

In the interest of clarity, we tweaked the message slightly to separate the statement that we don't monitor on weekends from the potential of being a client that needs to use a different form. It now reads:

> Please be aware that the support team does not monitor support tickets during the weekend or holidays.
>
> If you are on one of our Stack Overflow for Teams Enterprise or Business plans, we do offer on-call support. If this is an emergency, please open a Severity 1 or 2 ticket via our [support portal](https://s.tk/support). If your issue falls within our on-call SLA, someone should contact you within 15 minutes. For all other products and plans, we'll reach out as soon as we can the next business day.

Comment: Maybe adding "on" to this will make it more clearer: "*we'll reach out as soon as we can __on__ the next business day.*" Thanks for answering and fixing the "*you're*" typo.

Comment: Are https://support.stackenterprise.co/ and https://stackenterprise.freshdesk.com/ the same? They look very similar.

Comment: Since when did SE start sending the weekend email?

Comment: Yes the two URLs are aliases. We're trying to consolidate use of just one domain in all our communications. I'm not familiar with when this email was turned on - that info isn't recorded in the system.