# Response email from Stack Exchange contains link to https://portal.stackexchange.com which I can't access

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, contact

On 27 ‎February ‎2022, ‏‎02:20 PM (Indian Standard Time), I received an email from Stack Exchange  (refer [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377097) for details about the email) containing this link: https://s.tk/ooo (which redirected to https://portal.stackexchange.com/).

This is how it looked like:

[image]

I tried logging in with my Stack Exchange account details, but got an error:

[image]

What is this support portal meant for?

Also, the link no longer redirects to the portal.

[image]

Why did the redirection stop?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is an internal-only system previously used for out of office (OOO) notifications that has no relevance to the public. I have no idea how that link ended up in that message. We will fix it on Monday.

Comment: Guessing why it was sent: employee assigned for the ticket was Out Of Office, perhaps? So the system notified the one opening the ticket about it.

Comment: animuson, why did the redirection stop? Also, it would be great if you can address this post: [Why was a weekend support email sent when a normal user appealed a suspension using the contact form on Sunday?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377097).

Comment: The link was destroyed because we no longer use that system. It is in the tear-down process. // @Shadow No, it was just copy-pasted wrong. It was supposed to be https://s.tk/support